# from scrapy.utils.misc import load_object ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.utils'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to deploy scrapy project on my local, but I am seeing

'''

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapyd\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from scrapy.utils.misc import load_object
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.utils'
```

'''

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you installed Scrapy? Does `c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy` exist?

Comment: yes I have installed Scrapy and I see all file in c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy

Comment: Does `c:\users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\__init__.py` exist?

Comment: I seem to have the exact same problem.

Comment: I just uninstalled and installed scrapyd and scrapydweb again, now I don't see this issue.